# Show validation error on textfield by using sky floating label

Tags: swift, validation, uitextfield

Hi I using `skyfloatinglabel` text field in my application.
I want to show the error on text field.

I write validation like following it will show error but it will move to next screen how to me control that.

please find the error for:
`fullnametxt.text == " "`

```
func authendication()
    {
        let phoneNumber = phoneNumbertxt.text ?? ""
        let emailAddress = emailaddresstxt.text ?? ""
        let lastName = lastnametxt.text ?? ""
        let fullName = fullnametxt.text ?? ""

        // User Must Give The input for saving.
        if (phoneNumber.isEmpty) && (emailAddress.isEmpty) && (lastName.isEmpty) && (fullName.isEmpty)
        {
            phoneNumbertxt.errorMessage = "Enter email address."
            //self.showAlert("Alert!", "Fill All The Fields", "ok")
        }
        else if fullnametxt.text == " "
        {
            //self.showAlert("Alert!", "Must Fill The FullName", "ok")

            fullnametxt.errorMessage = "Full name"
            fullnametxt.errorColor = UIColor.appcolorlight
        }
}
```

Comment: Change else if fullnametxt.text == " "  to else if fullnametxt.text!.isEmpty

Comment: What has the posted code to do with moving to the next screen apart from doing the validation? I think we need more context.

Answer (score 0):

`fullnametxt.text == " "`. In this check `" "` this is not empty string, it contains space. As empty string would be this `""`.

Comment: If I understand OP correctly the validation is working fine and the question is about how to stop the app (user?) from moving to the next screen so this is more suitable as a comment.

Comment: Just return the code if validation fails. like
if (notValid) {
 return;
}
else {
//Push to next screen
}